# obj file breakdown error in face values

Tags: c#, opengl

I am trying to understand an obj file so I can break it down for importing.  Right now my sample is a simple pyramid, designed with 3ds max. There have been small errors with tutorial.

So far i understand, a bit, but these are loading ok:

```
v is vertex(point in space),  
vn is vertex normal(don't understand why needed) but imported ok
vt is vertex texture
```

but next in the file is f & s, like this:

```
s 4
f 1/1/1 2/2/1 3/3/1 
s 2
f 1/1/2 3/4/2 4/5/2
```

First I don't really get what `s` is and why it increments exponentially?

More important I don't get the breakdown of `f`, according to wikki:

```
f v1/vt1/vn1
```

to me this looks like `v1` is vertex, `vt` is texture, and `vn` is normal, but why would they repeat that in file? So I assume my guess is wrong.

OVERALL my problem is that my load object is able to populate everything except faces, unless faces is the same as polygons at the bottom of file which would then be 0, but that makes no sense either!

Please resolve my confusion, thanks!

here is code & file:

[code]

```
    public static ObjVolume LoadFromString(string obj)
    {




        // Seperate lines from the file
        List<String> lines = new List<string>(obj.Split('\n'));

        // Lists to hold model data
        List<Vector3> verts = new List<Vector3>();
        List<Vector3> colors = new List<Vector3>();
        List<Vector2> texs = new List<Vector2>();
        List<Tuple<int, int, int>> faces = new List<Tuple<int, int, int>>();

        // Read file line by line
        foreach (String line in lines)
        {
            if (line.StartsWith("v ")) // Vertex definition
            {
                // Cut off beginning of line
                String temp = line.Substring(2);
                temp.TrimStart( );

                Vector3 vec = new Vector3();

                if (temp.Count((char c) => c == ' ') == 3) // Check if there's enough elements for a vertex
                {
                    String[] vertparts = temp.Split(' ');
                    vertparts[3].Replace("\r","");

                    // Attempt to parse each part of the vertice
                    bool success = float.TryParse(vertparts[1], out vec.X);
                    success |= float.TryParse(vertparts[2], out vec.Y);
                    success |= float.TryParse(vertparts[3], out vec.Z);

                    // Dummy color/texture coordinates for now
                    colors.Add(new Vector3((float)Math.Sin(vec.Z), (float)Math.Sin(vec.Z), (float)Math.Sin(vec.Z)));
                    texs.Add(new Vector2((float)Math.Sin(vec.Z), (float)Math.Sin(vec.Z)));

                    // If any of the parses failed, report the error
                    if (!success)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Error parsing vertex: {0}", line);
                    }
                }

                verts.Add(vec);
            }
            else if (line.StartsWith("f ")) // Face definition
            {
                // Cut off beginning of line
                String temp = line.Substring(2);

                Tuple<int, int, int> face = new Tuple<int, int, int>(0, 0, 0);

                if (temp.Count((char c) => c == ' ') == 3) // Check if there's enough elements for a face
                {
                    String[] faceparts = temp.Split(' ');

                    int i1, i2, i3;




                    // Attempt to parse each part of the face
                    bool success = int.TryParse(faceparts[0], out i1);
                    success |= int.TryParse(faceparts[1], out i2);
                    success |= int.TryParse(faceparts[2], out i3); 

                    // If any of the parses failed, report the error
                    if (!success)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Error parsing face: {0}", line);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        // Decrement to get zero-based vertex numbers
                        face = new Tuple<int, int, int>(i1 - 1, i2 - 1, i3 - 1);
                        faces.Add(face);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        // Create the ObjVolume
        ObjVolume vol = new ObjVolume();
        vol.vertices = verts.ToArray();
        vol.faces = new List<Tuple<int, int, int>>(faces);
        vol.colors = colors.ToArray();
        vol.texturecoords = texs.ToArray();

        return vol;
    }


# 3ds Max Wavefront OBJ Exporter v0.97b - (c)2007 guruware
# File Created: 27.02.2016 07:40:58

mtllib test1.mtl

#
# object Pyramid001
#

v  -15.7732 14.1346 5.0964
v  -23.0566 0.0050 13.3650
v  -8.4899 0.0050 13.3650
v  -8.4899 0.0050 -3.1722
v  -23.0566 0.0050 -3.1722
v  -15.7732 0.0050 5.0964
# 6 vertices

vn 0.0000 0.5051 0.8631
vn 0.8889 0.4582 -0.0000
vn 0.0000 0.5051 -0.8631
vn -0.8889 0.4582 -0.0000
vn 0.0000 -1.0000 -0.0000
# 5 vertex normals

vt 0.5000 1.0000 0.0000
vt 0.0000 0.0000 0.0000
vt 1.0000 0.0000 0.0000
vt 0.0596 0.0000 0.0000
vt 1.0596 0.0000 0.0000
vt 0.0000 1.0000 0.0000
vt 0.5000 0.5000 0.0000
vt 1.0000 1.0000 0.0000
# 8 texture coords

g Pyramid001
usemtl wire_154215229
s 4
f 1/1/1 2/2/1 3/3/1 
s 2
f 1/1/2 3/4/2 4/5/2 
s 16
f 1/1/3 4/2/3 5/3/3 
s 32
f 1/1/4 5/4/4 2/5/4 
s 8
f 2/6/5 6/7/5 3/8/5 
f 3/8/5 6/7/5 4/3/5 
f 4/3/5 6/7/5 5/2/5 
f 5/2/5 6/7/5 2/6/5 
# 0 polygons - 8 triangles
```

[/code]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right about V/Vt/Vn. You need that again to know how faces are connected what are the texture coordinates and normals for each face. They don't repeat in the file, f 1/4/10 2/5/6 3/7/11 means that this face has verticec v1,v2, and v3 with texture coordinates at vt4,vt5, and vt7 and normals with coordinates vn10,vn6, and vn11. Note that the indices of v, vt, and vn are the same as the order that they appear in the obj file. I suggest that you ignore vt and vn for now and just try to show faces using the first number after f. For the previous example, you can connect v1, v2, and v3 and you should get the right face. Later you can add normals and textures as well to have the complete shape with texture and right lighting. Note that vt is only iseful when you have the image atlas that provides the texture. vts are actually referring to the coordinates of the image texture.

Comment: Thanks, I get it now, it decodes similar to the way bitmaps do, I think i may just rewrite the last part there then, the +1 will add when i get a reputation, also is "s" important?

Comment: also in this line: f 2/6/5 6/7/5 3/8/5 , is the second six is a vertx y point right, is it looking for this coordinate 13.3650 , or this one:  0.0050?

Comment: S is for shading and it means you should smooth the shading and it does not have to do any thing with the connectivity. No, the second 6 means that this face has a vertex (its second vertex) with coordinates accessible at the 6th vertex appeared in the obj file as v x, y, z.